new TextBox doesn't work properly when I scan barcodes
I'm working on this store checkout system where I can scan barcodes into TextBoxes on a UserForm. Next to each TextBox, there's supposed to be a Label showing the product name and price. I've got it set up so I can keep adding more TextBoxes as I scan more barcodes. But here's the problem: the order the barcodes show up in the TextBoxes is all over the place. The sequence on which TextBox the new barcode will appear is 1st, 2nd, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 1st... and so on.
Regarding the labels, they're only showing info from the first TextBox. I want it so that when I scan a new barcode, a new TextBox pops up automatically, and the new barcode shows up there.
Below is the code I'm currently using:
Private count As Integer

Private Sub BarcodeTextBox_Change()
    Dim scannedCode As String
    Dim foundProduct As Range
    
    ' Get the scanned barcode from the TextBox
    scannedCode = BarcodeTextBox.Value
    
    ' Search for the scanned product code in the "Products" worksheet
    Set foundProduct = Worksheets("Products").Columns(1).Find(What:=scannedCode, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not foundProduct Is Nothing Then
        ' Product found, retrieve information
        Dim productName As String
        Dim productPrice As Double
        
        ' Retrieve product name and price from adjacent cells
        productName = foundProduct.Offset(0, 1).Value
        productPrice = foundProduct.Offset(0, 2).Value
        
        ' Update labels to display product information
        ProductNameLabel.Caption = "Product Name: " & productName
        ProductPriceLabel.Caption = "Price: $" & Format(productPrice, "0.00")
        
        ' Populate the initial TextBox with the scanned barcode
        If BarcodeTextBox.Value = "" Then
            BarcodeTextBox.Value = scannedCode
        Else
            ' Add a new TextBox below BarcodeTextBox for continuous scanning
            AddNewBarcodeTextBox scannedCode, productName, productPrice
            SendKeys "{TAB}", False
        End If
    Else
        ' Product not found, clear labels
        ProductNameLabel.Caption = ""
        ProductPriceLabel.Caption = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewBarcodeTextBox(ByVal scannedCode As String, ByVal productName As String, ByVal productPrice As Double)
    ' Add a new TextBox and Label below BarcodeTextBox
    Dim newTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim newLabelName As MSForms.Label
    Dim newLabelPrice As MSForms.Label
    Set newTextBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    Set newLabelName = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    Set newLabelPrice = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    count = count + 1
    With newTextBox
        .Top = BarcodeTextBox.Top + (count * (BarcodeTextBox.Height + 5)) ' Position below the previous TextBox
        .Left = BarcodeTextBox.Left
        .Width = BarcodeTextBox.Width
        .Height = BarcodeTextBox.Height
        .Name = "NewBarcodeTextBox" & count
        .TabStop = True
        .SetFocus
    End With
    With newLabelName
        .Top = newTextBox.Top
        .Left = newTextBox.Left + newTextBox.Width + 5
        .Width = 100 ' Adjust label width as needed
        .Height = newTextBox.Height
        .Caption = "Product Name: " & productName
    End With
    
    With newLabelPrice
        .Top = newLabelName.Top
        .Left = newLabelName.Left + newTextBox.Width + 5
        .Width = 100 ' Adjust label width as needed
        .Height = newLabelName.Height
        .Caption = "Price: $" & Format(productPrice, "0.00")
    End With
    
    ' Increase UserForm height to accommodate new TextBox and Label
    Me.Height = Me.Height + newTextBox.Height + 5
    
    ' Center the UserForm on the screen
    CenterUserForm
End Sub

Private Sub CenterUserForm()
    ' Center the UserForm on the screen
    Me.Top = (Application.Height - Me.Height) / 2
    Me.Left = (Application.Width - Me.Width) / 2
End Sub

Below is an image of the Userform name

Let me know if there is any more information I should provide. Thank you in advance!

Did you set the TabIndex property for each one correctly? That's how it determines the order when TAB is pressed.

@taller apologies for that again! Please see above the updated image.

Why do you need to add a new textbox every time you scan - what is that for?

@TimWilliams The Initial TextBox (BarcodeTextBox) just writes down the barcode as I'm scanning it. It is just a reference for the Labels to lookup the product name and price. In the future, I was thinking about adding a another TextBox to the right of the ProductPriceLabel in case anyone were to haggle prices. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way and there's an easier path?

@braX I tried adding .AutoTab = True within the newTextBox step (was this what you meant?) and that sort of worked. The labels now say the correct product names and prices, but the TextBox still don't appear with the corresponding barcodes.

Why not just use the one textbox for scanning, and populate all the info for each scan in labels? In AddNewBarcodeTextBox you're placing an empty label next to the retrieved Product/Price info.
